# Docker suddenly stops working on my windows system

Tags: python, windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Docker stopped working on my windows 10 pc suddenly after some weeks not using it, i searched online for help and most of the solutions were about deleting some files in appData folder and restarting the pc which i did as instructed but still didn't work, The error traceback i'm getting when i try to open docker is :

```
System.TimeoutException:
The operation has timed out.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpOverStream.NamedPipe.NamedPipeDialer.<DialAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpOverStream.Client.DialMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.IPC.Client.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\IPC\Client.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.<GetJsonAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\HttpClientExtensions.cs:line 16
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.LifecycleClient.<GetDockerStateAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\LifecycleClient.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Docker.Engines.LinuxkitDaemonStartup.<WaitAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\LinuxkitDaemonStartup.cs:line 60
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 177
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<WaitCurrentTransitionsAsync>d__30.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 354
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merges\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 98
```

I have tried searching for other ways to solve the issue but there's little to no results online.

Comment: Are you stuck at engine starting?

Comment: yes,it keeps displaying ``` docker starting ``` then pops up this error after few minutes

Comment: I had the same problem recently, I uninstalled the docker desktop and reinstalled it and it fixed the problem. Note that I did lose all my containers and volumes doing that.